# how to create a timestamp with only date part showing in the table

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to create a column with timestamp type but only showing the date (without time).

I found a similar example on this site:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp

However, when I run this example SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
  OrderId int NOT NULL,
  ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE(),
  PRIMARY KEY (OrderId)
)
```

I got a syntax error.
I'm new to SQL, please help.

Thank you

Comment: I can't believe that w3schools is wrong on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store only the date, you can specify your type as `DATE`, then create a trigger to set the orderDate to `CURDATE()` like below.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
  OrderId int NOT NULL,
  ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  OrderDate DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (OrderId)
);

CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON Orders
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.OrderDate = CURDATE();
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40649/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

CURDATE() is a function and you cannot use it as a default value.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column. See Section 11.3.5, “Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP”.

That means you can solve it like this for example:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderId int NOT NULL,
    ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    OrderDate timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderId)
);
```

Let's insert something into this table:

```
INSERT INTO Orders(OrderId, ProductName) VALUES (1,'Foo');
```

Now select:

```
SELECT OrderId,ProductName,OrderDate FROM Orders;

+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| OrderId | ProductName | OrderDate           |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
|       1 | Foo         | 2014-01-20 02:12:27 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Above gives you date and time for OrderDate, if you would like date part only, then here is the solution:

```
SELECT OrderId,ProductName,DATE(OrderDate) AS OrderDate FROM Orders;

+---------+-------------+------------+
| OrderId | ProductName | OrderDate  |
+---------+-------------+------------+
|       1 | Foo         | 2014-01-20 |
+---------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.
It there a way to create the schema that works like timestamp with date info stored only? not through the "select" query.